# Recursive Set Challenge

Tags: logic, computability, turing-machines

we knoe
[image]

also we know 
[image]

for example if A be any arbitrary r.e set. can we always Necessarily the following is TRUE ? (always) any description is good. (bar sign means complement)

[image]

Comment: It is important here to define the Universe you are working in. For example if we assume the set of Integers is the set of all numbers we will consider, then the compliment to the set of integers is the empty set. But if set of Complex numbers is our universe then the compliment to the set of Real Numbers is still a decent subset universe, whereas there does exist a one to one mapping between all complex numbers and reals but there does not exist a one to one mapping between the empty set and set of all integers

Comment: What do $\leq_m$ and $\leq_1$ mean?

Comment: i add some detail.  Dear @frogeyedpeas without any universe consideration?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Fixing a universe of discourse is not a main problem. In this problem, the universe of discourse is the set of natural numbers. (The notion of computability is defined over natural numbers.)

Answer (score 2):

Every r.e. set is many-one reducible to the halting set $K$. That fact, together with the theorem you cited, immediately implies an affirmative answer to your question.

Comment: it means always this is true ? in fact the complement of K is not r.e, this is not conflict?

Comment: Dear @Andreas, Would you please say converse of the question is not always true ?

Comment: If the complement of $A$ is many-one reducible to the complement of the halting problem then, by the theorem you cited, $A$ is many-one reducible to the halting problem and is therefore r.e.  That is, the converse is true.